# about the args of matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array
i=1
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def animate():
    i= i+2
    x=x[1:] + [i]
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x))  # update the data
    return line,

#Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
    interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

I get error like this:animate() takes no arguments (1 given)..so confused.  i don't even give an arg to the callback func. Was there something that i missed?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is off, or at least unclear here: the function has an intrinsic first argument, the frame number. So you can simply define it as `def animate(*args)` or `def animate(framenumber, *args)`, or even `def animate(framenumber, *args, **kwargs)`.

See also [this example](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

Note that you'll run into other problems after that:

- `i` and `x` within `animate` should be declared `global`. Or better, pass them as arguments through the `fargs` keyword in `FuncAnimation`.
- `x = x[1:] + [i]` doesn't work the way you think it does. Numpy arrays work differently than lists: it would add `[i]` to every element of `x[1:]` and assign that to `x`, thus making `x` one element shorter. One possible correct way would be `x[:-1] = x[1:]; x[-1] = i`.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I have to say the documentation is too 'brief'. Hope it will be better...